# Conditional Rendering Based on Multiple Values in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hoping someone can help as I have been struggling with this for a few days.

I am new to Vue and my JavaScript skills are fairly average.

I am looking to display a colour coded icon based on which job roles the people have within the array have.

Green - Array contains Developer & Product Manager

Yellow - Array container Developer

Red - Array does not contain either Developer or Product Manager

The array is grouped into teams and setup like this:

```
0 { 0 { name: Bob Sinclair
        teamname: Francs
        email: bob.sinclair@test.com
        job: Product Manager
        type: Team Member
      }
  }
1 { 0 { name: Neil Jones
        teamname: Dream Team
        email: neil.jones@test.com
        job: Developer
        type: Team Member
      }

    1 { name: Jim Cairns
        teamname: Dream Team
        email: jim.cairns@test.com
        job: Product Manager
        type: Team Member
      }
    2 { name: Craig Ferguson
        teamname: Dream Team
        email: craig.ferguson@test.com
        job: Designer
        type: Team Member
      }
  }
2 { 0 { name: Stuart Daly
        teamname: SuperNova
        email: stuart.daly@test.com
        job: Developer
        type: Team Member
      }

    1 { name: Martin Black
        teamname: SuperNova
        email: martin.black@test.com
        job: Sales
        type: Team Member
      }
    2 { name: Rebecca Forbes
        teamname: SuperNova
        email: craig.ferguson@test.com
        job: Other
        type: Team Member
      }
  }
```

Here is my current HTML for what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="card-footer">
   <img class="group-image" v-for="(team, index) in teams" :key="team[0].teamname" v-if="developer == productManager" src="/Images/green%20group.png">
   <img class="group-image" v-for="(team, index) in teams" :key="team[0].teamname" v-if="developer"src="/Images/yellow%20group.png">
   <img class="group-image" v-for="(team, index) in teams" :key="team[0].teamname" v-if="neither" src="/Images/red%20group.png">
   <a href="https://community.global.hsbc/sites/DigiHub/SitePages/Hack-Chat.aspx" target="_blank">
   <img class="chat-image" src="https://community.global.hsbc/sites/DigiHub/SiteAssets/hub_assetts/Hack%20Teams/Images/chat.png">
</div>
```

And here is my JS (The if statements are at the bottom for the 3 data objects):

```
    var appTeamCards = new Vue({
    el: '#app-teams',
    data: {
        teams: [],
        developer: false,
        productManager: false,
        neither: false
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.getTeams();
    },
    methods: {
        getTeams: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sites/DigiHub/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'global-hackathon-reg\')/items?$orderby=Modified desc',
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var posts = data.d.results;
                    readData(posts);
                    console.log(self.teams);
                },
            });

            function readData(data) {
                self.teams = groupBy(data, "teamname");  
            };

            function groupBy(collection, property) {
                var i = 0, val, index,
                    values = [], result = [];
                for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
                    val = collection[i][property];
                    index = values.indexOf(val);
                    if (index > -1)
                        result[index].push(collection[i]);
                    else {
                        values.push(val);
                        result.push([collection[i]]);
                    }
                    // console.log(collection[i].hackertype);
                    if (collection[i].hackertype == "Developer") {
                        self.developer = true;
                    } else {
                        self.developer = false;
                    }

                    if (collection[i].hackertype == "Product Manager") {
                        self.productManager = true;
                    } else {
                        self.productManager = false;
                    }

                    if (collection[i].hackertype != "Product Manager" && collection[i].hackertype != "Developer") {
                        self.neither = true;
                    } else {
                        self.neither = false;
                    }

                    // console.log(self.developer);
                    // console.log(self.productManager);
                    // console.log(self.neither);
                }
                return result;

            }

        }
    }
});
```

The code at present does not display any icons and the only other result I'm getting is that they all display as green.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you clarify more

Comment: the array that you provided in beginning is not clear

Comment: Sure, apologies if i'm not explaining this correctly. So the array is currently set to group by team name. Each team name is an object with the team members inside also as objects. The team names are displayed as bootstrap cards and when clicked displays the members of the team and their job. I'm looking to have a colour coded icon based on the state of the team. E.g if the team has a "developer" & "product manager" then this would show "green". If the team has 1 of the 2 then this would show "yellow". If the team had neither then this would show "red".

Comment: please provide a clear example of your group

Comment: Updated the post, does this make more sense?

Comment: where do you want to show the members? in cards, modals  or what?

Comment: The teams show as cards and then the members are shown in a modal when clicked. That part is working by using index as ID and then binding this to the modal. I also want to show a colour coded icon at the bottom of each card  that shows the state of the team based on the conditions above and that's the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: the structure of your  group array makes trouble

Comment: I thought it might be an issue but has worked for everything up until this point. In general to add this functionality would I be looking at something like find() or filter() methods? Or a forEach()? Something like that?

Comment: execuse me, i'm tired and i gonna sleep, tomorrow i will review your problem